# Como executar um grupo de suites no JUnit?

Tags: java, junit

Tenho as seguintes suites abaixo:

```java
@RunWith(Suite.class)
// this other matters
@Suite.SuiteClasses({
        TestC.class,
        TestB.class,
        TestA.class
})
public class MySuiteA {}

@RunWith(Suite.class)
// this other matters
@Suite.SuiteClasses({
        TestD.class,
        TestE.class,
        TestF.class
})
public class MySuiteB {}
```

Como eu faria uma suite ou teste que rodasse o `MySuiteA` e `MySuiteB`?

Comment: Eu achei que apenas por marcar como resolvido vc já ganhava os pontos. [=

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Nada te impede de criar uma suite de suites:

```java
@RunWith(Suite.class)
@SuiteClasses({ com.package1.MySuiteA.class,
                com.package2.MySuiteB.class })
public class RunAllTests {

}
```

**Referência:** [Launch Suite classes using another Suite class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19810125/launch-suite-classes-using-another-suite-class) (em inglês)

---

Por outro lado, o fato de você estar tentando agrupar Suites dispara meu *spider-sense*. Será que você realmente precisa de suites de suites? Qual seu objetivo?

Talvez você esteja procurando dividir seus testes conforme algum critério:

- Para categorizar testes (e.g., rápidos e lentos) e escolher quais você deseja incluir / excluir de uma Suite de uma olhada na funcionalidade de [Categorias](https://github.com/junit-team/junit/wiki/Categories) (em inglês).
- Se você deseja executar testes conforme determinado perfil do Maven, a funcionalidade de Categorias casa muito bem com a funcionalidade de perfis. Para mais informações veja o artigo *[Using JUnit @Category and Maven profiles to get stable test suites](http://technicaltesting.wordpress.com/2012/09/24/using-junit-category-and-maven-profiles-to-get-stable-test-suites/)* (em inglês).

Se você der mais detalhes sobre o problema que está tentando resolver ficarei feliz em ajudá-lo com maiores sugestões.

Comment: Eu havia testado assim antes mas a IDE não deu start no s testes. Agora que eu testei novamente ele foi. Não entendi o que aconteceu mas funcionou. Obrigado. [=

Comment: Eu realmente preciso de suites para realizar testes para o EasyCriteria. Com ele eu tenho diversos testes que tem que ser executados para cada implementação do JPA. Criei uma suíte para cada implementação e queria uma que rodasse tudo. [=

Comment: Entendi. E boa sorte com seu Projeto :). Sobre rodar uma suite para cada implementação de JPA, ainda acho que esse é um bom exemplo de categorização. Inclusive te ajuda caso você tenha testes compartilhados entre diversas implementações. E.g.: `@Category({Hibernate.class, EclipseLink.class, OpenJPA.class, DataNucleus.class})`

Comment: Sobre o IDE, caso seja o Eclipse, eu pessoalmente adquiri alguns preconceitos contra o suporte nativo dele para o JUnit (peguei a época do [ClasspathSuite](http://johanneslink.net/projects/cpsuite.jsp). Já que você usa Maven, aproveite o [SureFire](http://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/), [Failsafe](https://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-failsafe-plugin/) etc e esqueça o IDE :D.

Comment: Hum... Interessante a proposta. Na classe Hiberante.class eu poderia adicionar @BeforeClass por exemplo? Eu estou utilizando o idea e ele tava travando. O.o

Bem, eu rodei o teste na unha e foi. [=

Comment: uaiHebert. Sim, você pode anotar tanto classes quanto métodos com classificadores. Depois na Suite você escolhe quais categorias devem ser incluídas ;). Dá uma olhada no link de Categorias na minha resposta que ficará mais claro.

Comment: Blzma. Valeu. [=